# Preventing memory leaks with JNI return object

Tags: java, c, memory-leaks, java-native-interface

I've got some C code that implements a JNI method to return a `jobject` back to Java when called. In the C code, I faff about for a bit with a `struct` that looks a bit like this:

```
typedef struct {
    char* something
    int somethingElse
} awesomeStruct;
```

In the C library, I `malloc` some memory for the struct, and also for the `char*`.

When it comes to return the `jobject` at the end of the JNI method, I do something like this:

```
awesomeStruct *mystruct = getResult();
jstring somethingString;
jint somethingElseInt;

somethingString = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env,mystruct->something);
somethingElseInt = mystruct->somethingElse;

ret = (*env)->NewObject(env,javaClass,method,somethingString, somethingElseInt);

return ret;
```

Hopefuly, this should call `method` method on `javaClass` with the two parameters of the string and the int that was in the struct.

Given that `getResult()` does a `malloc` for the struct and the char array, how do I free this? If I try to free either `mystruct` or `mystruct->something` before the return statement, I get `Debug assertion Failed - CrtlsValidHeapPointer` errors, which I guess is due to the fact the return object contains references to things that no longer exist once I call free.

How do I stop this leaking?

Comment: Your code looks OK to me (but wait for a better answer just in case I am completely wrong) Perhaps the error is related to the way you are allocating memory for `awesomeStruct *mystruct` or `char* something` and because of that you get `Debug assertion Failed - CrtlsValidHeapPointer` while trying to free the allocated memory. If you are completely sure you are allocating memory in the right way, you can forget this comment.

Comment: `getResult()` simply does a `awesomeStruct mystruct = (awesomeStruct*)malloc(sizeof(awesomeStruct));` I'm not completely sure if this is the 'right' way or not, but my limited knowledge tells me that I should be freeing this at some point.

Comment: Right, you must release the allocated memory. And what about `char *something`? Hehe, just for curiosity :P

Comment: I forgot - I do a `malloc` on that as well as the struct. `malloc` the struct, then malloc the `char*` inside.

Comment: you should be able to free mystruct->something just after the call to NewStringUTF and be able to free awesomeStruct * just after the call to NewObject. You may have a "double free" problem if you free mystruct->something in the mystruct DTOR AND elsewehere.

Comment: @growse Well, I am not an expert but if I were you I would try to free(mystruct->somethingElse) and then free(mystruct). Not just one free but 2. Did you try that?

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I was indeed freeing the `char*` first, then the struct. Does NewStringUTF create a jstring on the Java memory stack which is then GC'd?

Comment: Sorry, I did not see you have NO dtor in awesomeStruct... Not a double free problem, then...

Comment: @growse AFAIK Right. But again, I am not an expert.

Comment: @growse How are you assigning the c-style string to your newly malloc'd `something` within your `awesomeStruct`? `strncpy`? `strcpy`?

Comment: I was using `strncpy` as this thing has to be portable across Windows / Linux and also not use C99, so `strlcpy` is out (I believe). I believe I'm doing this correctly, but should I explicitly check for a null terminator to see if that's causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've had similiar issue with JNI Memory Leak on C side There was an allocated Strings (UTF Char arrays stayed still on Memory), I solved it with JNI memory release commands it was something like that;

```
(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env,jmessage,message);
```

It realy solves my problem so,Maybe if you have look at this documentation on this Web site it could be solution for you;

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html